# Conditions for which conservation of energy works

Tags: energy-conservation

I was solving the following problem, and the first idea I had was conservation of energy.

> **27.19. Fusion Reactor.** If two deuterium nuclei (charge $+e$, mass $3.34 \times 10^{-27}$ kg) get close enough together, the attraction of the strong nuclear force will fuse them to make an isotope of helium, releasing vast amounts of energy. The range of this force is about $10^{-15}$ m. This is the principle behind the fusion reactor. The deuterium nuclei are moving much too fast to be contained by physical walls, so they are confined magnetically. (a) How fast would two nuclei have to move so that in a head-on collision they would get close enough to fuse? (Treat the nuclei as point charges, and assume that a separation of $1.0\times 10^{-15}$ is required for fusion.) (Source: University Physics, Young and Freedman)

However, I realized that you couldn't use the formula for potential energy $k\frac{q_1q_2}{r}$ because the field of any of the deuterium nuclei is changing. However, I did realize that this could be solved by work-energy theorem. If I set the origin as the midpoint of the two particles, then if one deuterium nuclei is at position $x$, the force that the other deuterium nuclei exerts is $k\frac{e^2}{(2x)^2}$, where $k$ is Coulomb's constant. Then the work done is
$$\int_\infty^{5.0\times 10^{-16}} k\frac{e^2}{4x^2} dx = 1.15\times 10^{-13}\text{ N}$$
This is the change in kinetic energy or $0 - \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, and solving for $v$ gives $v = 8.3\times 10^6$ m/s.

The actual answer however is $\sqrt{2}$ times what I got, or $1.2\times 10^7$ m/s, which would be the answer given when conservation of energy is used.

Why does work-energy theorem fail to work here, and why does conservation of energy work here? Did the book make a mistake?

Comment: You miscounted the work done: you get a contribution of $\int F dx$ from both particles, since they're doing work on each other. So your energy should be bigger by a factor of 2.

Comment: @knzhou I'm confused by what you mean. I thought work-energy theorem applied to total work done on a single object.

Comment: @knzhou Please don't give wrong answers in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the work done is fine, and the book is wrong.

However you should get the same answer when you use conservation of energy correctly.

Work is the work done on a single particle, and you used it to find the kinetic energy of a single particle. And thence the speed of that single particle.

Potential energy is always the potential energy of the system. So a change in potential energy of the system equals the change in kinetic energy of the system. So when you use the potential energy you get the kinetic energy of both particles so you have to divide by two to get the kinetic energy of just one particle. And then you get the same (and correct) answer. Which differs from your book because your book is just wrong.

If you are used to the earth's gravitational potential energy then the earth is pulled up when a projectile falls down. And the changes in momentum are equal. But kinetic energy is $p^2/2m$ so the much much more massive Earth gets a much much smaller kinetic energy so when you divide up the kinetic energy between the projectile and the earth, then almost all of the energy goes to the projectile. You convert a certain amount of potential energy into total kinetic energy. Each object gets an equal amount of momentum and the earth gets almost no kinetic energy for that amount of momentum gained.

If you've studied equally massive objects gravitating then you'd already be familiar with this.

As for when energy conservation calculation works, there are a few limitations. One is speed. Kinetic energy isn't actually $p^2/2m$ it is $$-mc^2+\sqrt{(\vec pc)^2+(mc^2)}.$$ However this is very close to $p^2/2m$ when the speed is much smaller than $c$. Another limitation is that you used the the electro*static* force even though your charges are moving. But that would mess up your calculation of work too. This means your particles need more kinetic energy to get that close to account for the  energy lost, for instance, to radiation as they accelerate.